# Default content type when exception thrown

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have some controller method that should return Word docx document:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile() {
    Resource file = storageService.loadTemplateResource();
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
            .body(file);
}
```

When file is found everything is ok, however when `storageService.loadTemplateResource()` throw exception it produces empty body.

How can I get Sprng default content type when exception has been thrown (both `text/html` and `application/json`)?

EDIT:

When I remove `produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"` from `@RequestMapping` annotation I get default Spring error resposne:

text/html:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.  
Tue Feb 06 16:22:51 CET 2018  
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).  
No message available
```

or application/json:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2018-02-06T15:27:18.881+0000",
  "status" : 404,
  "error" : "Not Found",
  "message" : "No message available",
  "path" : "/api/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you want to show when an exception is thrown?

Anyway you need to add an exception handler for the controller for the exception which your method throws to handle the logic if an exception is thrown

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) // Exception/Throwable class you like to catch
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE) // Change or skip this depending on the response you want to build
            .body("Response which you wanted to show");
}
```

Or just return a template name without the `@ResponseBody` and use a templating engine like JSP/Thymeleaf to build the response instead of manually building the response.

---

Edit:

Spring boot should translate any RuntimeExceptions into HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) so you should also see a whitelabel error page for any runtime exceptions thrown. Are you sure your `loadTemplateResource` method actually throws an exception instead of returning a *null* Resource object or something?

You could test by manually throwing an exception by `throw new RuntimeException()` in your controller method and check if you see a whitelabel error page or a blank page. Which Spring version are you using btw?

If you want 404 instead of 500 you could create a new Exception class like below and throw that instead.

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Regarding your edit:
The reason you are seeing the error message as mentioned in your edit is not due to exception in your `loadTemplateResource` but because when the DispatcherServlet can't find a handler for a request it sends a 404 response and since error mapping is absent it will show a whitelabel 404 page.

Comment: But how can I get this error message as default spring error response?

Comment: I updated my answer after seeing your edit. Check if it helps